# Opening a file on the desktop regardless of username

Tags: python, txt

I'm trying to open a file on my laptop with Python and to do that I have the following code:

```
filem = open("C:\\Users\\david\\Desktop\\project\\last_msg_m.txt")
```

This works fine but I'm trying to adapt it so that it works independent of username so I used the following:

```
filem = open("C:\\Users\\"+ l1 +"\\Desktop\\project\\last_msg_m.txt")
```

However it doesn't work so I was wondering if there is another way to do it?

Comment: How are you setting the value of the variable `l1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Simply use `%userprofile%\desktop` or `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` as mentioned in the comments.
2. Otherwise you can also make use of the `os` module:

```
import os
username = os.getlogin()    # Fetch username
file = open(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\project\\last_msg_m.txt') # Use username var in f string
```

Comment: @Matiiss I did, it works

Answer (score 0):

**Windows only** (to my knowledge):
So I tried using `%userprofile%` but it didn't seem to work for me so here is a different way to get it:

```py
import os

user_profile = os.environ.get('USERPROFILE')

with open(fr'{user_profile}\Desktop\path\to\file') as file:
    # do things with file
```

Using environment variables (also I suggest using context managers to open files)